# Converting JS Using Google.Math.Long to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am converting some Javascript code into C# and having a bit of trouble with the Google math longs and how the function. This is actually a version of the Delphi random function - according to my co dev.

In javascript I have this.

```
function _nextRandom(maxValue, seedValue) {
    if (seedValue !== null) 
        _seed = new goog.math.Long(seedValue);

    _seed = _seed.multiply(134775813).add(_one);
    _seed = new goog.math.Long(_seed.getLowBitsUnsigned());
    return _seed.multiply(new goog.math.Long(maxValue)).getHighBits() >>> 0;
}
```

In C# I have this - so far.

```
private int _nextRandom(int maxValue, int seedValue)
{
    if (seedValue != 0)
        _seed = seedValue;

    _seed = _seed * 134775813 + 1;
    _seed = (long)((int)_seed); // get lower 32 bits
    return (int)(((ulong)_seed * (ulong)maxValue) >> 32); // get upper 32 bits
}
```

Max value is always 254 and the first time _nextRandom is run seedValue is 1024 every other time afterwards its 0 (in C#) or null (in JS)

[image]

Here the output from the C# is correct only for positive values, negative ones are incorrect

[image]

Casting the values as byte makes the values nearly match but not exactly.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- You have declared `_seed` to be a 64 bit `long`. It should be a 32 bit `int`.
- You need to cast `_seed` and `maxValue` to `uint` before performing the 64 bit multiplication.

The following C# code replicates the Delphi PRNG:

```
private static int _seed = 0;

private static int _nextRandom(int maxValue, int seedValue)
{
    if (seedValue != 0)
        _seed = seedValue;
    _seed = _seed * 0x08088405 + 1;
    return (int)(((ulong)(uint)_seed * (uint)maxValue) >> 32);
}
```

Obviously this code is not threadsafe but I am sure you already know that. A cleaner implementation would be to wrap this in a class so that you could create distinct instances of the PRNG with their own seed.